# hibernate table per month

Tags: java, hibernate

I've a conception problem with Hibernate for my application.

Actually, my project needs to communicate with PLCs and record a lot of variables. In some cases, the application should be able to record 100 000 values per day (or more).

So, to reduce tables size, how can I record a value in one table per month with Hibernate ? (Ex. : table name *'201401_records'*, *'201402_records'*, *'201403_records'*, ...)

Class example :

```
public class Record
{
    private long id;
    private GregorianCalendar eventDate;
    private String value;
    private Variable variable;
    ...
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: 100k values a day is not so very much. A normal relational database is able to cope with that. You should not prematurely optimize, before you really face a problem. You could consider moving older records to an archive table.

Comment: Is it possible with Hibernate to set up automatic archiving ?
Moreover, I saw a concept about partitioning a table. Can I do it with Hibernate ? With all databases or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Uwe Allner already mention about archiving. You can archive to csv files as well. About the periodic backup process, you can use [Quartz Shedular](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-quartz/)

Comment: Hey, it seems to be a nice solution. I will take a look to Quartz Schedular. Thanks.